# How to share Skype group chat link to allow friends to join?

Tags: windows-7, windows, skype

I know there is a Skype command to get a link for my group chat:

```
/get uri
```

It will return a link like:

```
skype:?chat&blob=GPswtk_abc...def_kvPikkUFUWzoA36MbIURXc
```

But when I share this link with my friends they cannot join and gets an error saying that the Administrator is not online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to fix it is to set the correct permissions to the group chat:

Just run this two commands (as the chat administrator) before getting the uri:

```
/set options +HISTORY_DISCLOSED
/set options +JOINING_ENABLED
```

Now run:

```
/get uri
```

And share the link with your friends.

Every new joinner will also be able to see the history of the chat.